# Pulumi push docker image to GCR

Tags: docker, pulumi

I'm learning how to use Pulumi and I'm wondering I can correctly configure pulumi to push images to GCR. I have the following in `index.ts`

```js
const appImage = new docker.Image("ledgerImage", {
    imageName: 'us.gcr.io/qwil-build/ledger',
    build: "../../",
});
```

When I run `pulumi preview` I see that the image is successfully built:

```
 2:51PM /Users/paymahn/qwil/ledger/pulumi/infra pulumi ⬆ ⬇ ◼
 ❮❮❮ pulumi preview
Previewing update (qwil/dev):

     Type                                 Name                  Plan       Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                  ledger-dev            create     1 message
 +   ├─ docker:image:Image                ledgerImage           create
 +   ├─ gcp:compute:Address               cloud-sql-private-ip  create
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core:Service           ledger                create
 +   ├─ gcp:servicenetworking:Connection  private_vpc           create
 +   ├─ gcp:sql:DatabaseInstance          ledger_db             create
 +   ├─ gcp:sql:SslCert                   clientCert            create
 +   ├─ gcp:sql:User                      master                create
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core:Secret            ledger-db-tls         create
 +   └─ kubernetes:extensions:Deployment  ledger                create     1 warning

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (ledger-dev):

  kubernetes:extensions:Deployment (ledger):
    warning: extensions/v1beta1/Deployment is not supported by Kubernetes 1.16+ clusters. Use apps/v1/Deployment instead.

Resources:
    + 10 to create

Permalink: https://app.pulumi.com/qwil/ledger/dev/previews/3f96f06f-ba49-4f52-91db-2884389a6b62
```

However, when I visit the permalink I see the following output in the Diff Log view at the very end of the image build step: `Successfully pushed to docker`. When I visit our private GCR repo I don't see any updates/new pushes of the image.

My questions are:

1. Does Pulumi push the image when previewing?
2. When pushing, does pulumi decide on the repository based on the image name?
3. If yes, why does the output of my preview say the image was pushed to docker?

Comment: Looks like that log statement doesn't have any docker registry awareness: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-docker/blob/382476abd12673abc97e08da8e4b5f3849858e06/sdk/nodejs/docker.ts#L178

Comment: There's some precedent to not perform pushes during preview: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-cloud/commit/ee52cb5df856524ecc4370f12e1ec368568880df

Not sure if this applies in my case since that code change happened in `aws/docker.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your questions:

1. During preview, the `Image` resource will build the image and return the target image name, without pushing. During a normal update, it will do the same, as well as tag and push the image.
2. Yes.
3. The output is a bit confusing here, see (1).

Here is an example of a docker image pushed to GCR, worked for me just yesterday: https://github.com/pulumi/examples/pull/519/files#diff-982498c859f8161c992d7246993ab441R48-R53